# mysql limiting the number of rows in a comparison based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "my_table" with 2 columns

```
 1. Timestamp (ts)
 2. Value (val)
```

I need to return for each timestamp, the average of 10 latest values that occur on or before the timestamp.

I am able to do something similar with the following query:

```
SELECT t2.ts as time, 
       AVG(t1.val) as avg_val 
FROM table_name as t1, table_name as t2 
WHERE t1.ts <= t2.ts
```

This returns a timestamp and the average of all the values that occur on or before that timestamp. I need to modify this query to return the average of the 10 latest values and not all the values.

PS: Apologies for a bad question title. Was not sure how to frame it.

Comment: 1. Please stop using comma based joins. Use more explicit `Join` based syntax. 2. It is a window function problem with frame. What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: The MySql version is 5.6.35.

Comment: As far as I can see, you need a lateral table expression, and MySQL doesn't support those.

Comment: Can you elaborate on lateral table expression.

Comment: What @TheImpaler means what lateral SQL i assume he means a SQL keyword what makes it possible to use the outer sql columns in the inner sql with subqueries or joins or more less.. Basically it can be simulated in MySQL with a co-related subquery.

Comment: @user3828311 the accepted answer (mine) is incorrect. Unaccept so that I could delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore previous answer. You can use "poor man's rank" to rank the rows sorted by timestamp. You can join the result by itself for find previous 9 rows for each rank:

```
SELECT a.ts, AVG(c.val)
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ts, COUNT(t2.ts) AS rank
    FROM t AS t1
    INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t2.ts <= t1.ts
    GROUP BY t1.ts
) AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.ts, COUNT(t2.ts) AS rank
    FROM t AS t1
    INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t2.ts <= t1.ts
    GROUP BY t1.ts
) AS b ON b.rank BETWEEN a.rank - 9 AND a.rank
INNER JOIN t AS c ON b.ts = c.ts
GROUP BY a.ts
```

I understand it is a bit clunky but it could be better than correlated sub queries under certain conditions.

Comment: This doesn't work.  The average is calculated before the `limit`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to express this query in MySQL prior to version 8 -- even using variables.  I'm not going to vouch for performance, but this should do what you want:

```
SELECT t1.ts, t1.val, AVG(t2.val)
FROM t t1 LEFT JOIN
     t t2
     ON t2.ts <= t.ts AND
        t2.ts >= (SELECT t3.ts
                  FROM t t3
                  WHERE t3.ts <= t1.ts
                  ORDER BY t3.ts DESC
                  LIMIT 9, 1
                 )
GROUP BY t1.ts, t1.val;
```

Of course, in 8+, this is simply:

```
select t.*,
       avg(t.val) over (order by ts rows between 9 preceding and current row) as avg_10
from t;
```

Comment: This almost works except that it skips the first 9 rows.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . It is not clear what the OP wants when there are not 10 previous values, but it is reasonable that the OP wants those rows.  A `LEFT JOIN` fixes that.